# Unabled to install (unknown chipset) Ubuntu since I changed from a GTX 570 to a GTX 970

Tags: nvidia

I think my title is pretty self explanatory but I get the message "unknown chipset" when I'm trying to install Ubuntu.

It seems to be since I changed my graphic card from the GTX 570 to a GTX 970. I even used an old iso I used before and I had the same issue.

Here is a list of messages I'm getting :

```
unknown chipset
failed to create 0x80000080
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache: write through
enter help for a list of buil-in commands.

initramfs
```

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while now. I tried various kernel and driver combos but nothing seemed to work.

Now it seems like the latest kernel (3.13.0-49) and xorg.edgers nVidia driver (nvidia-349) updates have fixed the "unknown chipset" problem. To get those updates you'll either have to use onboard graphics if your CPU/motherboard has onboard or drop back to the old GPU temporarily.